# The grammar of "or"

Tags: grammar

Is it true that the verb of a sentence has to follow the second subject connected by or? For example:

1.You or I am correct.

2.You or she has a book.

3.Are you or I wrong?

4.Are the pencil or books new?

Comment: None of those sentences sounds at all natural; I think native speakers would express them differently to avoid the problem. For example, *Either you are correct or I am."

Comment: English verb agreement is not built to handle disjunction. Avoid using disjoined subjects and you will have no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, I can't stand it it when someone answers a reasonable grammar question with "Just reword it", rather than answering the question, but in this rare case, "Just reword it" *is the correct answer*.

No matter what verb form you use --before or after the compound subject-- it will sound wrong. Any rule about which verb form to use there is just a *prescriptivist* rule, and can be safely ignored, so although it probably sounds *slightly less wrong* to follow that rule, it will still sound wrong. A native speaker would reword to avoid this problem:

> 1. <del>You or I am correct.</del> --> "One of us is correct."  OR "Either you're correct or I am."
> 2. <del>You or she has a book.</del> --> "One of you has a book." OR "Either you have a book or she does."
> 3. <del>Are you or I wrong?</del> --> "Are you wrong or am I?" OR "Is one of us wrong?"
> 4. <del>Are the pencil or books new?</del> --> "Is the pencil new or the books?" OR "Is either of the pencil or the books new?"